# Obtaining keyspace hit and miss from Redis

Tags: redis, monitoring

Is there a programmatic way to obtain the `keyspace_hits` and `keyspace_miss` values programmatically through some REST or Groovy API?

Answer (score 9):

You can get these stats programmatically through the normal Redis interface:

```
> INFO
...
keyspace_hits:414197256
keyspace_misses:661663278
...
```

See the [INFO command](http://redis.io/commands/info) documentation for more.

Redis doesn't speak HTTP; it only speaks the Redis protocol. You could put [webdis](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis) in front if required.

Comment: Thanks, i'm aware of INFO. But I was wondering how to obtain it's content through an API. I checked Jedis but it doesn't seem to have a method that maps to the INFO command.

Comment: It looks like you just call [`Jedis.info()`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/redis/clients/jedis/2.0.0/jedis-2.0.0-javadoc.jar!/redis/clients/jedis/BinaryJedis.html#info()).

Answer (score 1):

You can usually get all the info you need from just connecting to the server with any redis client.

You can get all the info by using this command [Info](http://www.redis.io/commands/info).

There is an interesting article [here](http://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/03/redis_get_set.html) that the Author shows how to trace gets and sets and messing around with the redis source code.

There is some third party tools that lets you monitor redis a quick google search you give you a few like [this one](http://www.logicmonitor.com/monitoring/databases/redis/). (I am not endorsing them it is just an example).

There is also the [monitor](http://www.redis.io/commands/monitor) command in redis that shows you everything as it happens which you could make your own monitoring app.